# Unable to get my ports set up correctly when load balancing between Apache and 2 Tomcats all in Docker Containers

Tags: docker, apache, tomcat, load-balancing

I am trying to set up a test to learn about load balancing, but I have not been able to get all of the settinga working correctly.  I have tried many variations on the settings over a couple of days, but I am unable to get it all working correctly.

I have 1 docker container running apache server and 2 docker containers running tomcat to serve a webpage.  The apache is to be used as a load balancer between the two tomcats. Why am I unable to access my load balanced websites on the tomcats  at webapps/blah/index.html with the following set up?

I am able to ping between the containers.

### Docker

Checking the docker port configurations and ip addresses:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND              CREATED      STATUS          PORTS                                                 NAMES
069d7a807cec   tomcat:9.0-jdk11-openjdk   "catalina.sh run"    5 days ago   Up 29 minutes   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8084->8084/tcp, :::8084->8084/tcp   tomcat4
4f260c3e0638   tomcat:9.0-jdk11-openjdk   "catalina.sh run"    5 days ago   Up 58 seconds   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, :::8083->8083/tcp   tomcat3
d4abb29c37de   httpd                      "httpd-foreground"   5 days ago   Up 46 hours     0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp, :::8082->80/tcp
```

```
# docker inspect bridge

        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "069d7a807cec20cfae90e7c5f913440d691ad576c555b53d79cb2c59505e6bb3": {
                "Name": "tomcat4",
                "EndpointID": "f7bf5a42f1ad9caa4b3f6a2333b567178aba79bfa8804d0fb3af6c82a9d59b9e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "4f260c3e063809f124bd8a6fe2f22ab474b340282b83692d65bb0b4cfb56adce": {
                "Name": "tomcat3",
                "EndpointID": "21ee68b206fcfd9577a92d575e100544ef5400c481389b597db307509ecdbc63",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d4abb29c37dedef040aafdb6aeb5e9f91cdef8a8c6c5a41537a2d831c3345636": {
                "Name": "httpd2",
                "EndpointID": "5783e5a537fc2617b9bd0122e4653554d86b1b18cb7c040c8aebf00221945b3c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
```

The Apache server has the following set up in httpd.conf (amongst the rest):

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

Listen 80

ServerName: 172.17.0.2
```

mod_proxy_http, mod_proxy_balancer and mod_proxy are all loaded and Included.

The Apache server has the following set up for load balancing:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        CustomLog logs/access.log combined
        ProxyRequests off
        <Proxy balancer://lbcluster>
                BalancerMember http://172.17.0.3:8083 route=tomcat3
                BalancerMember http://172.17.0.4:8084 route=tomcat4
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / balancer://lbcluster/
        ProxyPassReverse / balancer://lbcluster/
</VirtualHost>
```

### Tomcat Configuration

My tomcat3 and tomcat4 have a folder webapps/blah which contains a file index.html which contains basic html.

tomcat3 has the following in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
               maxConnection="200" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="172.17.0.3" jvmRoute="tomcat3">
```

If I try to access blah using:

```
lynx http://172.17.0.2:8082/blah
```

I get a 503.

I get the following in the access.log:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2023:10:16:51 +0000] "GET /blah HTTP/1.0" 503 299 "-" "Lynx/2.9.0dev.12 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/3.7.7"
```

Going straight to tomcat3 gives me:

```
lynx http://172.17.0.3:8083/blah
```

give

```
Alert!: Unexpected network read error; connection aborted.
Can't Access `http://localhost:8083/blah'
Alert!: Unable to access document.
```

If I go into tomcat3 and run the following command inside the container,

http://localhost:8080/blah

I get

```
Unable to connect to the remote host
```